# How to update Microsoft Edge VM to latest dev version?

Tags: microsoft-edge

We I to test [latest](http://dev.modern.ie/platform/changelog/10525-pc/) dev version of Microsoft Edge web browser. So I downloaded corresponding [virtual machine](http://dev.modern.ie/tools/vms/mac/), logged in with my insider Microsoft accound and selected update to "fast" as shown on this screenshot:

[image: insider builds]

Unfortunately, clicking on "check updates" brings nothing: it displays "system is up-to-date" and stuck with build 10240. Is it possible to update Edge version on such VM?

Comment: This is not a programming question, I'm sorry to say.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it seems that no proper way exists. The solution that worked for me: search for preview build iso torrent and install preview version into vm. Normally torrents are available next day a new preview build is out.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this, it's the official Microsoft tool to perform build 10240 upgrade :

Go to https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Click on "Upgrade Now" under "The Update Assistant can help you update to the latest version of Windows 10";